# Android Soft Keyboard not showing

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have added a custom keyboard to my existing activity by following this tutorial : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

But I don't know how to show that keyboard ? I have seen several ways, but none of them worked in my case. The last one i tried was :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput( 0, 0 );
```

Here is the service declaration in the android manifest :

```
<service
    android:name=".SimpleIME"
    android:label="@string/simple_ime"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.view.im"
        android:resource="@xml/method" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
    </intent-filter>            
</service>
```

Here is the keyboard layout, which is a different file than the layout loaded in the activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview" />
```

The preview.xml (from the tutorial) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffff00"   
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp">
</TextView>
```

And my IME-based class :

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements OnKeyboardActionListener
{
    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;

    private void playClick( int keyCode )
    {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch( keyCode )
        {
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView()
    {
        kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.keyboard, null );
        keyboard = new Keyboard( this, R.xml.qwerty );
        kv.setKeyboard( keyboard );
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener( this );
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey( int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes )
    {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        playClick(primaryCode);

        switch(primaryCode)
        {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;

        default:
            char code = (char) primaryCode;
            if( Character.isLetter( code ) && caps )
                code = Character.toUpperCase( code );
            ic.commitText( String.valueOf( code ), 1 );                  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress( int primaryCode )
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease( int primaryCode )
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onText( CharSequence text )
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp()
    {
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ? How can i show THIS keyboard and not the android's default one ? (which is not showing either)

Thank you.

EDIT : I found a checkbox in the `settings / language et input` without label but that was related to the keyboard of my application. I checked it to allow the use of the keyboard, but it's still not showing up.

EDIT 2 : I also selected my keyboard in `settings / language and input / default`, but same result.

EDIT 3 : The keyboard actually shows up when using another application... :-/